# Copy a SQL record from a backup and insert into database, keeping the primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to restore a single row in a table which has been deleted. I have the row in a backup copy of the database. I know that I can copy / paste from one database to another, however (obviously) doing this doesn't keep the primary key value, so it looks like a new record.

How can I insert this row into a table, and keep the original primary key value (which is unique)? There are other tables which reference this keyid, so doing this will prevent us having to make changes elsewhere.

Comment: I assume your primary key is an auto incrementing integer? Are there no foreign keys to this table? How are there records elsewhere which reference this?

Comment: Are you thinking it won't keep the original pkey value because the field is autoincrement? You should be able to explicitly insert the old value. I.e., include it in the list of fields to insert, and the db won't default it to the next sequence.

Comment: Please provide details of what both your tables look like.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is an IDENTITY Column (which performs an auto-insert of an INT/BIGINT which increments) then you would need to run the SET IDENTITY_INSERT command.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Id, Columns) SELECT Id, Columns FROM BackupDb.dbo.MyTable WHERE Id = DeletedRowID 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable OFF;
```

Here's the MS Doc related to this command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

Any other type of primary key (such as a Unique Identifier populated by NEWID() should not require IDENTITY_INSERT to be turned on.

Also note that only 1 table can have IDENTITY_INSERT turned on at a time, and the account issuing the command must own or have the ALTER permission on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table is set up like this

```
create table tableWithAutoId (id int identity(1,1) primary key, val varchar(50))
```

Just doing this (which is basically what you want) will fail

```
insert into tableWithAutoId(id, val)values(1,'abc')
```

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tableWithAutoId' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

However if you turn on [Identity_insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) first you can ignore the `Identity` property on the column

```
set identity_insert tableWithAutoId ON
insert into tableWithAutoId(id, val)values(1,'abc')
```

Be sure to turn it back OFF when you're done

```
set identity_insert tableWithAutoId ON
```

Answer (score -2):

insert into  (column list)
select (column list) from 
where  = value